# Fixing broken network adapters on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Recently I tried to install VirtualBox and Hyper-V to browse a VHD file but the installations kept failing and I believe I know why.

Here is a screenshot of my network adapters in Windows 10 Settings App:

[image]

As you can see my mouse seems to be hovering over a non-existant network adapter. I have had this problem ever since I installed Astrill VPN and it accidentally removed one of my adapters that I was currently using.

That adapter did reinstall but my computer never seemed to truly fix itself, for example here is the network popup:

[image]

which as you can see seems to think my primary network is a non-internet accessible vm'ed adapter.

Is there any way to "reset" the network in Windows 10 without losing all my installed adapters while fixing any network adapter problems I may currently have?

### Edit

This what my network adapters screen looks like:

[image]

and my device manager:

[image]

Comment: What do you see when clicking *Change adapter options*? How about in Device Manager, Network adapters with View/Show hiddern devices turned on?